# How enable non-privileged user to connect using rsh?

Tags: rhel, rsh

I have two hosts with Red Hat 7.4 , HostA and HostB.
The rsh-server and rsh packages was installed in both.
At both hosts, the rsh deamon was activated, the commands `rsh,rlogin,rexec` was added to `/etc/securetty`, at `/etc/hosts.equiv` the `HostA` and `HostB` was added.

From **hostA**, with root, when I run `rsh hostb`, connects successfully without ask password.
From **hostA**, with any other user, give the error : `rcmd: socket: Permission denied`.

From **hostB**, with root, when I run `rsh hosta`, connects successfully without ask password.
From **hostB**, with any other user, connects successfully without ask password.

I already try add the set bit : `chmod +a $(which rsh)` , but have no effect. 
The SELINUX is disabled on both hosts.
The firewall is disabled on both hosts.

Comment: Try giving rsh and the user `CAP_NET_ADMIN` or `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user/17685265#17685265 for more info)

Comment: I update my question with more details. As you can see they work only from one host to another, but not the inverse.

Comment: be sure that `rsh` is not `ssh` in disguise, from memory access control is set by `host.allow`/`host.deny` and `.rhosts` in `$HOME` dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this solved.
But unfortunately I do not discover why this happen.

When I run at hostA :

```
# getcap /bin/rsh
```

They return nothing.
At hostB they return :

```
getcap /bin/rsh
/bin/rsh = cap_net_bind_service+ep
```

I just remove the package and reinstalled using `yum` and then they get the permissions.

But why that occur at first ? 
What is missing at first time it was installed ?
Weird.

Comment: You can run `rpm -V $(rpm -q -f /usr/bin/rsh)` periodically to make sure it's still installed correctly.